# Why is my code/data/bss segment so high in memory?

Tags: linux, linker, virtual-memory

I used to believe that when an ELF image is loaded into RAM, the addresses of the code/data/bss segments, the stack and heap are assigned from the lowest to the highest. So when I ran something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ext;

int main(void) {
    printf("%p\n", &ext);
    return 0;
}
```

the result was somewhere within a 24-bit interval. To my surprise, when I installed a Linux distro from scratch on another machine, I'm getting addresses like 0x55ae11d1e034 (both machines are 64-bit).

I tried various things like playing with `ulimit`, `/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax`, `setarch` and yet I can't get the damn addresses to the first 4 GB.

Can somebody explain what is happening here and why?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual address space (the high addresses) isn't limited to the available RAM size. That's the whole point of [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).
Typically there's no need to control the load addresses.

If you do want to have addresses (any random address may not work -- needs to be a multiple of page size), you can pass the linker option `-Ttext-segment`:

> -Ttext-segment=org
>    When creating an ELF executable, it will set the address of the first byte of the text segment.

See the man page of [`ld(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html).

For example, compiling your program on my machine with shows:

```
$ gcc -Wl,-Ttext-segment,0x10000000 test.c
0x10201014
```

Comment: All right, that explains how to change it to my liking. But still doesn't explain the 'why' part. Is there something like a default setting for the linker? If so, what would be the point of setting it to different values in various Linux distros?

Comment: What you see is likely due to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). Search `randomize_va_space` in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt

Comment: I'm familiar with that setting. While this does stop randomizing the addresses, they are still >4 GB (in comparison to the other 64-bit machine where the addresses are in the lower area by default). I'd like to know what causes this difference and why.

Answer (score 1):

> I used to believe that when an ELF image is loaded into RAM, the addresses of the code/data/bss segments, the stack and heap are assigned from the lowest to the highest.

You are mistaken. The code/data/bss were never (at least not since 1970s) assigned from the *lowest* address: the zero page has been left alone with no-access protections in order to catch NULL pointer dereferences.

In addition, a non-PIE binary can not be loaded at arbitrary location, only at the location where it was linked to load (but that default address used to be quite low: `0x400000` on `x86_64`).

Finally, stack was never assigned from the lowest address. On machines where stack grows towards lower addresses (such as all i*86 and x86_64), stack is allocated at the *highest* addresses, so as to leave the most space for stack to grow downwards and/or for heap to grow upwards (towards each other).

> Can somebody explain what is happening here and why?

You are getting a position-independent executable.

Traditionally, `x86_64` executables on Linux were linked at address `0x400000`. Output of `file` on such an executable:

```
$ file /bin/date
/bin/date: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked ...
```

Newer distributions configure their GCC to produce `PIE` binaries instead (making certain attacks, such as known-address attacks, slightly harder).

When you run `file ./a.out` on a PIE binary, you see this:

```
$ file ./a.out
./a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked ...
```

Such executables are relocated before they start executing, usually into `0x55..........` address range on `x86_64`.

You can link a non-PIE binary by passing `-no-pie` to the link command.